# Infimum of the supremum absolute value of a decreasing sequence of subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ with non-empty intersection

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, supremum-and-infimum

Let $K_{n}$ be a decreasing sequence of bounded subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ such that $\cap_{n}K_{n}=K\neq\emptyset$. Let $\lambda_{n}=\text{sup }_{\lambda\in K_{n}}|\lambda|$ and $\lambda_{0}=\text{sup }_{\lambda\in K}|\lambda|$. Then $\{\lambda_{n}\}$ is a decreasing sequence of positive numbers bounded below by $\lambda_{0}$. Is it true that $\lambda_{0}=\text{inf }\lambda_{n}$? It seems like it should be true, I would be grateful for  a hint on this!

Comment: It would be more precise to write "decreasing sequence of subsets" instead of "sequence of decreasing subsets". This becomes particularly important when subsets are replaced by functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, this is false. Let $K_n = \{0\}\cup (1-1/n,1 )\subset \mathbb{R}$, for example: then $\lambda_n=1$ for all $n$ but $\lambda_0=0$.

If $K_n$ are compact, this is true. Let $\lambda = \inf \lambda_n$ and consider the sets $A_n = K_n \cap \{z: |z|\ge \lambda\}$ which are nested, compact, and nonempty. Conclude that $K \cap \{z: |z|\ge \lambda\}$ is nonempty, hence $\lambda_0\ge \lambda$. The reverse inequality is clear.

Comment: What if the $K_{n}$-s are only bounded, and not compact? Under the hypothesis, $\cap_{n}K_{n}\neq \emptyset$ but can it happen that $\cap_{n}A_{n}= \emptyset$ if the $K_{n}$-s are not compact?

Comment: I misread your question as if compactness was assumed... edited my answer now.